# How to attach click events on selected links for a page using jQuery?

Tags: jquery, jquery-selectors

Hi I am using following code to attach event to links on the page.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $("a").click(function(){
     ..... do something
   });
  });
```

But I don't want to do this for all the links. I want to do this for few selected links. Can anyone help how can I achieve this?

Answer (score 3):

Add a class to all of the links you want to add click events for, then:

```
$('.thatClassName').click(function(){ ... });
```

Answer (score 0):

Add a `class` to the links you want to affect, then change your selector to `$('a.className')`.

Answer (score 0):

Refine your selector - instead of all links, target them by class, id, or parent etc.

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
 $(".myClass1, .myClass2, #myId").click(function(){
 ..... do something
```

});
  });

Answer (score 0):

```
$(document).ready(function(){ 
     $(".className1").click(function(){     /*Action1*/   });
     //or
     $("#id1").click(function(){     /*Action2*/   });
  });
```